# How to custom mask input in React Native without using libraries?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, masking, input-mask, react-native-text-input-mask

I am completely new to react-native and have been trying to custom mask input. However, I am only getting numbers more than 10 even if I have specified the mask under TextInput. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Please see my code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, TextInput } from "react-native";


export default class InputMask extends Component {

    state = {
        mask: '',
    }

    customMask = (mask) => {
        if ( typeof mask == 'String') {
            for (let i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {

                if ( mask == '9') {
                    return mask.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')
                }
                if ( mask == 'a') {
                    return mask.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '')
                }
                if ( mask == 's') {
                    return mask.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '')
                }
                if ( mask == '*') {
                    return mask
                }
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            mask: mask.substring(0, mask.length) || ''
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    mask= '(999) 999 9999'
                    placeholder="Enter phone number"
                    value={this.state.mask}
                    onChangeText={this.customMask}
                    style={styles.input}
                    keyboardType="phone-pad"

                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
    input: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly seems like the mask props you are trying to pass to RN TextInput are not available you can look through [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) to see available props. Secondly, seems like the way you are approaching is not the way you want to proceed  I recommend you understand how and what the props for text input give and do then start creating a custom component. For your masked input you can external libraries like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mask-input) (not promoting just an example) as they exist to make our lives easier but if you are still keen on making custom components you can browse through their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/CaioQuirinoMedeiros/react-native-mask-input) and see on how they have implemented it and try something similar like [this](https://github.com/CaioQuirinoMedeiros/react-native-mask-input/blob/main/src/MaskInput.tsx).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have to implement a custom mask input for an existing huge codebase for a mobile application and they are trying not to use libraries.